# Storing passwords while keeping the integrity of getch()

Tags: c++, windows, console

Whats an easy way I can store the password the user inputs while still keeping the password hidden?

```
  char password[9];
   int i;
   printf("Enter your password: ");
   for (i=0;i<9;i++)
   {
   password[i] = getch();
   printf("*");
   }
   for (i=0;i<9;i++)
   printf("%c",password[i]);
   getch();
   }
```

I wanna store the password so I can do a simple `if (password[i] == root_password)` so the proper password continues on.

Comment: Any particular reason you're using `getch` in C++ instead of `cin.get`?

Comment: No reason. Couldn't find any other suitable ways.

Comment: @Cody: getch doesn't echo the input, unlike typical cin.get()

Answer (score 0):

Your problem appears to be that you're not checking for newline '\n' nor end-of-file.

```
printf("Enter your password: ");
char password[9];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < sizeof password - 1; i++)
{
    int c = getch();
    if (c == '\n' || c == EOF)
        break;
    }
    password[i] = c;
    printf("*");
}
password[i] = '\0';
```

This way, password will end up being an ASCIIZ string, suitable for printing with `puts`, `printf("%s", password)`, or - crucially...

```
if (strcmp(password, root_password)) == 0)
    your_wish_is_my_command();
```

Note that we read at most 8 characters into the password as we need one extra character for the NUL terminator.  You could increase that if you wanted.

Comment: Why does it say all my variables for this section are undeclared when they are?

Comment: Josh: are you including the necessary headers for printf() and getch(), strcmp() if you're using it too?  Otherwise, I can't say without seeing your exact code - why don't you paste it into your question above, and list the exact compiler error and line number...?

Comment: You're not using sizeof correctly there. Firstly, you're missing ( ), and it returns a size in bytes. In place of the whole hoopla with sizeof, you could've just put 10. The -1 hinders you, as the < is a less than, not less than or equal to operator.

Comment: Im using cstring, stdio, cmath, and iostream libraries.

Comment: @Josh: sizeof doesn't need `(` and `)` unless the argument is a type (though I was once told an old MS C++ compiler was broken in that regard).  It is a keyword and not a function call, as per `return`, and I prefer not to encourage readers to confuse the two things by unnecessarily invoking either like a function.  I could have put `;i < 8;` (not 10) in the `for`-loop condition, but that then breaks if you change the number of elements in `password` - that's not a good habit.  If you need more help, please post your exact code.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the console API in Windows. Below is a snippet that disables echoing in the console window. The function `SetConsoleMode()` is used to control the echoing (among other things). I save the old mode, so that I can restore the console once the password has been retrieved.

Also, the `*ConsoleMode()` functions need a handle to the console input buffer. How you can get a handle to these buffers is described in the MSDN documentation of `CreateFile()`.

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    char password[100] = { 0 };
    printf("Enter your password: ");

    HANDLE hConsole = ::CreateFile("CONIN$", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, 0);

    DWORD dwOldMode;
    ::GetConsoleMode(hConsole, &dwOldMode);
    ::SetConsoleMode(hConsole, dwOldMode & ~ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);

    bool bFinished = false;
    while(!bFinished) {
        if(!fgets(password, sizeof(password) / sizeof(password[0]) - 1, stdin)) {
            printf("\nEOF - exiting\n");
        } else
            bFinished = true;
    }

    ::SetConsoleMode(hConsole, dwOldMode | ENABLE_ECHO_INPUT);
    printf("\nPassword is: %s\n", password);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since we are in C++ and Windows do this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <conio.h> //_getch
#include <Windows.h> //VK_RETURN = 0x0D

using namespace std;

string read_password()
{
    string pass;
    cout << "Enter your password: ";

    int character = 0;
    while(VK_RETURN != (character = _getch()) )
    {
        cout << '*';
        pass += static_cast<char>(character);
    }

    cout << std::endl;
    return pass;
}

int main ()
{
    string root_password = "anypass123";
    string pass = read_password();

    if (pass == root_password)
    {
        cout << "password accepted" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

compiled & tested